Stationary distributions in Markov chains
This question is with regards to HMMT Guts 2021/28 and 2018/27.

Caroline starts with the number $1$, and every second she flips a fair coin; if it lands heads, she adds $1$ to her number, and if it lands tails she multiplies her number by $2$. Compute the expected number of seconds it takes for her number to be a multiple of $2021$.

The answer is $4040$. Here is the solution:

Consider this as a Markov chain on $\mathbb{Z}/2021\mathbb{Z}$. This Markov chain is aperiodic (since $0$ can go to $0$) and any number can be reached from any other number (by adding $1$), so it has a unique stationary distribution $\pi$, which is uniform (since the uniform distribution is stationary). It is a well-known theorem on Markov chains that the expected return time from a state $i$ back to $i$ is the inverse of the probability $\pi_i$ of $i$ in the stationary distribution. (One way to see this is to take a length $n \to \infty$ random walk on this chain, and note that $i$ occurs roughly $\pi_i$ of the time.) Since the probability of $0$ is $\frac{1}{2021}$, the expected return time from $0$ to $0$ is $2021$. After the first step (from $0$), we are at $1$ with probability $\frac12$ and $0$ with probability $\frac12$, so the number of turns it takes to get from $1$ to $0$ on expectation is $2 \cdot 2021 - 2 = 4040$.

I attempted this problem from 2021 a while ago, and I kinda understood the solution (although I have never heard of the "well-known theorem" before). But I'm still kind of confused about how the "probability of $0$" is $\frac{1}{2021}$, and what the word "probability" even means here. I guess "on average" you would expect to end up at $1/2021$th of the time, but I don't know why that's true, other than a vague sense of "well there are $2021$ numbers, something something symmetry". Also, I don't know what "aperiodic" means in this context. I googled it and "periodic" means "the chain can return to the state only at multiples of some integer larger than 1". It's not so hard to verify that this chain is indeed aperiodic (since you can go from $0 \to 0$ in $2021$ steps by repeatedly adding $1$, but also in $1012$ steps from $0 \to 1 \to \dots \to 1010 \to 2020 \to 2021$, and $\gcd(2021,1012) = 1$), but I don't see how that follows from the fact that $0$ can go to $0$.
Later, I tried 2018/27:

There are $2018$ frogs in a pool and there is $1$ frog on shore. In each time-step thereafter, one random frog moves position. If it was in the pool, it jumps to the shore, and vice versa. Find the expected number of time-steps before all frogs are in the pool for the first time.

Here is my "solution": By "symmetry", the equilibrium probability of all frogs on the shore is $1/2^{2019}$, so the expected amount of time to go from "all frogs on pool" to "all frogs on pool" is $2^{2019}$. Now the expected amount of time to go from "all frogs on pool" to "$1$ frog on shore" is $1$, so the answer is $2^{2019} - 1$.
The actual answer is $2^{2018} - 1$. I suppose the Markov chain isn't periodic here because you can go back to a position after an odd number of steps, but there's no way it's a coincidence that the answer is $2^{2018} - 1$ when I got $2^{2019} - 1$. What's going on here? Is there some sort of generalization of the "well-known theorem" from before that gives a clean way to solve this flavor of problem?

You need to go through a basic introduction to markov chains [e.g. chapter 11 in Grinstead and Snell's book https://math.dartmouth.edu/~prob/prob/prob.pdf -- theorem 11.15 will be of interest]. Aperiodicity is addressed in any such intro and it also irrelevant to the problem; the thing that matters is there is a single communicating class. In your problem if you look at the ring of integers mod $2021$ the operations of addition by 1 and multiplication by $2$ are invertible [$2 \cdot 1011 =1$] which implies the transition matrix is doubly stochastic giving the uniform stationary distribution.

There was an error in the answer key on HMMT Feb 2018 Guts #27 (as mentioned in the apology letter that year). They incorrectly plugged in $n=2018$ instead of $n=2019$, so $2^{2019}-1$ is indeed the correct answer (I think).

Ah okay, I understand now.
